# Kotlin - assign value of enum to variable without .value

Tags: enums, kotlin

What it's like now:

```
class Trial {
    companion object{
        @JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>){
            val message = Message.ALREADY_REGISTERED.value
            println(message);
        }
    }
}

enum class Message constructor(val value: String){
    ALREADY_REGISTERED("You've already been registered")
}
```

This outputs: `You've already been registered`. But I was wondering, is there a way to just assign `val message = Message.ALREADY_REGISTERED` and have the value immediately without having to use `.value`?

When trying this (with the code I want)

```
class Trial {
    companion object{
        @JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>){
            val message = Message.ALREADY_REGISTERED
            println(message);
        }
    }
}

enum class Message constructor(val value: String){
    ALREADY_REGISTERED("You've already been registered")
}
```

it outputs `ALREADY_REGISTERED`.

So can I make the value of the enum return default instead of it's name?

Comment: The question looks like you are asking for an implicit type conversion `Message -> String`, while you are probably not.

Comment: Well that would be a workaround but quite possibly could work

Comment: `constructor` is superfluous

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to override [`toString()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-string.html) for your `enum class`:

```
enum class Message(val value: String) {
    ALREADY_REGISTERED("You've already been registered");

    override fun toString() = value
}
```

You can also use [class delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html#class-delegation) if you want to be able to treat your enum class as a `CharSequence` (like `StringBuilder` and other `String`-like classes):

```
enum class Message(val value: String) : CharSequence by value {
    ALREADY_REGISTERED("You've already been registered");

    override fun toString() = value
}
```

Then you can use it just like any other `CharSequence`. e.g.:

```
buildString {
    append("Message received: ")
    appendln(Message.ALREADY_REGISTERED)
    appendln()
    appendln("Don't forget to do your laundry.")
}
```

Comment: thanks, just wondering: why is the semicolon required? Because compiler will think that I'm trying to declare another enum?

Comment: Correct, see [Anonymous Classes - Enum Classes - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html#anonymous-classes) for details. See also the [grammar for enum classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#enum-classes).

Comment: This only seems to work when using println, if message is changed to `val message: String = Message.ALREADY_REGISTERED` the same problem is still present

Comment: I've updated my answer. You cannot extend `String` but you can get close. Java/Kotlin does this in lots of places with the `CharSequence` interface which `String` implements. In fact, when ever you define methods that receive a `String` and you do not require that input `String` to be immutable then you should use `CharSequence` instead for this exact purpose (e.g. take a look at the various methods in the [`kotlin.text`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/) package).

Comment: Hmm then the `.value` will be easier haha. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Or simply use `toString()` explicitly.